# How to distinguish swipe down from scroll down

Tags: android, scroll, swipe

The device makes mistakes with down swipe(fling) and scrolling down on a listview.
Has anyone run into this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: I suppose you could detect finger speed... But maybe you should rethink a UI that does vertical scrolling and vertical swiping at the same time. It's bound to be confusing, no matter how well you implement it.